# ¿Cómo insertar un salto de línea en medio de un string e imprimir caracteres especiales? (CMD, BATCH, PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, batch

Esta función lleva días dandome problemas. Voy plantear los dos que me quedan por resolver aquí para no tener que abrir dos hilos mas con esta misma función.

Con está función estoy leyendo el texto de un archivo y guardandolo en una variable (hasta ahí perfecto).

```
::La codificación de Windows ANSI Latin 1 (1252) resolvió el problema de los acentos
chcp 1252


set TEXTO="
for /f "Tokens=* usebackq Delims=" %%x in (archivo.txt) do (set linea=%%x)  & call :concadena    
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%"
echo %TEXTO%
goto :eof



::Salto de linea código ASCII 10
set SALTODELINEA="◙"
:concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%%linea%%SALTODELINEA%
goto :eof
```

El primer problema es que me gustaría insertar un salto de línea después de cada línea y no hay maneara, he probado con esto '^', con esto '\n' incluso con la combinación de teclas (Alt+10) para poner el código ASCII correspondiente al salto de línea y nada funciona.

Es decir, ahora mismo tengo el texto así.

> Soy la primera línea de un texto que está dando un montón de problemas. Soy la segunda línea del mismo texto que da problemas.

y quisiera tenerlo así

> "Soy la primera línea de un texto que está dando un montón de problemas.
>
> Soy la segunda línea del mismo texto que da problemas."

¿Alguna ídea de como resolverlo?

---

### ------------------EL SEGUNDO PROBLEMA YA ESTÁ RESUELTO---------------

### Hubo que poner todos los archivos con la misma codificación (ANSI Latin 1) y usar el comando (chcp 1252)

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------

El segundo problema es que el texto contiene acentos y al pasarlos a la variable se pierden y aparece este simbolo �. Algo así.

> "Soy la primera l�nea de un texto que est� dando un mont�n de problemas. Soy la segunda l�nea del mismo texto que da problemas."

He probado a usar el comonado  **(chcp 850 y chcp 65001)** para intentar cambiar el código de página a UTF-8 o algo que me reconozca los acentos pero no funciona.
¿Alguna alternativa?

---

### ------------------POSIBLE SOLUCION PROPUESTA EN PYTHON ---------------

Solucion que en principio parace buena pero que tambien tiene problemas

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import os, sys
import subir2
from os.path import basename



# usage: llamar.py DescripcionFilePath keywords


def main(args):     


    #Archivo de la descripcion (.txt)
    DescripcionFilePath = args[0]
    #remplazar extension txt por mp4
    VidepPath = DescripcionFilePath.replace("txt", "mp4")
    #conseguir el nombre del archivo sin extension
    Title = basename(DescripcionFilePath).replace(".txt", "")       


    #Abrir el fichero con la descripción y leer
    f =  open(DescripcionFilePath + ".des", 'r')
    texto = f.read()

    #Generar argumentos de la llamada
    new_args = ['--file='+ VidepPath,'--title=' + Title, "--description=" + texto, "--keywords=" + args[1],  '--category="10"', '--privacyStatus="public"']
    print(new_args)

    subir2.main(new_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Con este código vuelven a fallar los acentos, y si la cambio la codifiacion del archivo (.py) a ANSI me sale este error SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf3' in file C:\Users..../llamar.py on line 23, but no encoding declared; see y ni haciendo lo que dide aqui se soluciona.

Y si lo dejo en UTF-8 a pesar de quesalgan mal los acentos entonces obtengo este error.
**llamar.py: error: the following arguments are required: --file**

No estoy seguro pero creo que es porque pithon agrega una barra invertida en el path del archivo así

```
**'--file=h:\\careta1\\careta2\\video.mp4'**
```

Este archivo lo estoy llamando con un (.bat)  usando el siguente scirpt en CDM

```
@echo off

::Windows 1252 ANSI Latin 1
chcp 1252



set  DirTrabajo=%1
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


if "%~1"=="" (
    echo No se han introducido parametros:
    echo Introduzca la ruta del directorio de trabajo como primer parametro
    pause
    exit    
) else (
    echo Directorio de trabajo: %DirTrabajo%
)


set BatchFileDir=%~dp0
call "%BatchFileDir%\keywords.bat"
set PYTHON=C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
echo Directorio Trabajo: %DirTrabajo%



echo Obtener el nombre y la ruta de los videos a procesar:
for /R %DirTrabajo% %%G in (*.txt) do ( 
    set DescritionPath=%%G
    set FileName=%%~nG
    ) & call :subirVideo
::pause
goto :eof


:subirVideo
echo Subiendo Video:
%PYTHON% "%BatchFileDir%/llamar.py"  "%DescritionPath%"  %KEYWORDS%
goto :eof
```

---

### ------------------EL PRIMER PROBLMA ESTÁ SOLUCIONADO ----------------

Lo público como respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes generar una nueva linea visualmente tal como se indica en esta otra [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940/8409870), pero no se puede asignar a una variable. No queda claro tu objetivo, pero puedes usar un fichero temporal para conseguir una linea nueva.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=Do not remove this line=%
)

echo Linea1!\n!Linea2 > temporal.txt
echo Con comillas "!\n!line2" >> temporal.txt
```

Para tu segunda pregunta. Muy posiblemente la codificación de tu fichero origen no sea la misma que la de la consola (usa la página [850](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_850)). Con el comando `chcp` consigues cambiar la página de códigos, pero ha de ser la misma que la que tenga tu fichero archivo.txt. Si has usado el bloc de notas de windows será la 1252.

```
REM Página de códios Windows 1252
chcp 1252
REM UTF-8
chcp 65001
```

Espero que te sirva

**Editado**: *usando Python*

Si dispones de Python en tu sistema te recomiendo usarlo para conseguir tu objetivo. Para ello habría que modificar ligeramente el código de tu subir.py. Debes crear una función main como en este ejemplo:

```
def main(args):
    # Aquí debes poner tu código principal, lo que antes estaba en
    # if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
    argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
    argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
    argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
    argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
    default="")
    argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    if not os.path.exists(args.file):
    exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

    youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
    try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
    except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Con esto consigues que subir.py se pueda seguir llamando igual desde el CMD, pero haces posible que se pueda llamar desde otro fichero .py hecho por ti. Ese nuevo fichero si puede tener cadenas de texto con retornos de carro. Sería algo así, llamar.py:

```
import subir

#Abrir el fichero con la descripción
f =  open('archivo.txt', 'r')
#Recuperar las lineas en formato texto
texto = f.read()

#Generar argumentos de la llamada
args = ['--file', 'nombre_fichero', '--title', 'Título', '--description', texto]

subir.main(args)
```

llamar.py debe estar ubicado en el mismo directorio que subir.py. Al usar llamar.py generaria los siguientes parametros para tu subir.py:

```
λ llamar.py
Namespace(category='22', description='Soy la primera línea de un texto que está dando un montón de problemas. \nSoy la segunda línea del mismo texto que da problemas.', file='nombre_fichero', keywords='', title='Título')
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Es una pena que no sirva para una variable... es que lo necesito en una variable porque es uno de los argumentos de entrada para un ejecutable que no he escrito yo, todo va perfecto escepto por esos inconvenientes. Lo de los acentos es algo raro, el código 1252 me sirve a medias, porque los que escribo directamente en el código si salen bien pero los que están en esa variable siguen tieniendo ese problema. A ver si, se puede solucionar por medio del CMD, si no voy a hacer algo en C++ a ver si se soluciona, y es una lata porque si no fuera por esto sería perfecto.

Comment: @IvánRodríguez, lo de los códigos de páginas es algo lioso. Si en todos los sitios (txt origen, consola y cmd/bat) usas la  misma codificación no tendrás este problema. Pero si en alguno cambias de codificación, necesitarás un programa externo que te haga la transformación.
¿Podrías ampliar la información del argumento de entrada del ejecutable? Por si fuera posible otra solución

Comment: La verdad es que no tengo ni idea de en que codificación está el **archivo.txt** ... Los he generado automaticamente con otro programa que hice en C++ todos contienen el mismo texto y solo cambian en unos cuantos detalles (enlaces a ciertas páginas web)... En el CodeBlocks lo tengo en Sytem Default (A saber) y en NotePad++ en UTF-8 sin BOM (A saber) :-) Si es un lío.

Comment: Si en el Notepad++ te indica UTF-8, en la consola debes usar `chcp 65001`. Y lo mismo en el fichero .cmd donde tengas tú código.

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo, el problema debe ser entoces la codificación del .txt, No sé si estará usando la del sistema..

Comment: El .txt está codificado en ANSI....lo acabo de ver con el NotePad++... Voy a ver si puedo poner el BAT en ANSI también.

Comment: Ok, Perfecto!! :-) Poner todos los archivos en codificacion ANSI y usar el comando (chcp 1252) ha resuelto el problema de los acentos!! Muchas gracias @Mallenat ya solo queda un problema que resolver!!

Comment: Para el 1er problema, amplia la información sobre la entrada el .exe. Es muy raro pasar una cadena de texto con retornos de carro como entrada en un .exe

Comment: Es un programa hecho por google en python, sirve para subir videos a YouTube. La cadena de Texto es La descripción del video.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video?hl=es-419

Comment: le paso los argumentas así:
%PYTHON% "%BatchFileDir%/subir.py" --file=%VIDEOPATH%  --title="%FileName%" --description=%DESCRIPCION% --keywords=%KEYWORDS% --category="10" --privacyStatus="public"

Comment: @IvánRodríguez, he ampliado la respuesta usando Python como base. Espero que esto te acerque mas a tu solución definitiva

Comment: Si, es muy buena idea, de hecho casí me funciona. Aunque tengo un error porque el archivo tiene caracteres especiales.     **texto = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1854: character maps to <undefined>**

¿Alguna forma de que no pase esto?

Comment: Buena idea,  y casí funciona. Aunque ahora ha vuelto el problema de la codificación de los acentos. Y si la cambio a ANSI me sale este error **SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf3' in file C:\Users\..../llamar.py on line 23, but no encoding declared; see** y ni haciendo lo que dide aqui se soluciona http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Y si no lo cambio la codificación me sale este otro error **llamar.py: error: the following arguments are required: --file
['--file=h:\\...\\...\\...\\video.mp4',...**  Creo que es por la *doble barra*, python se la ha puesto así sin mas. Voy a poner el código ahí arrba a ver si ves algun fallo.

Comment: He averiguado que el script de google también elimina los saltos de línea del parametro "--description" porque hice un programa en C++ para intentar darle todo el texto... vaya lata... creo que la única opción que queda es reimplementar el código de google para que acepte saltos de línea o que deje sur un archivo con la descrición directamente. ¿Alguíen sabe como ponerse en contacto con google developers?

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución. Como bien decia @Mallenat era mas fácil leer el archivo desde PHYTON. Buscando por ahí dí con un código viejo, que tenía exactamente lo que estaba buscando. :-)

La solución (para mi) has sido añadir esto a la función main:

```
  argparser.add_argument('--description-file', dest='description_file', 
    help='Description file', default=None)



  args = argparser.parse_args()


      #utf-8
      if args.description_file is not None and os.path.exists(args.description_file):
        with open(args.description_file, encoding="latin-1") as file:
          args.description = file.read()
```

La información la saqué de aquí:
https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/blob/master/youtube_upload/main.py

Aprovecho para dar las gracias a Google por dar una información tan detallada y precisa de como usar su API (Es sarcasmo).

Quien si se merece las gracias y bien merecidas es @Mallenat por molestarse e invertir su tiempo en ayudarme,  además gracias a él he aprendido un poco de python. Anque sinceramente cada vez que aprendo algo de un lenguaje nuevo me doy cuenta de lo maravilloso que es el C++.

Pues eso, he puesto tanto código ahí arriba que ya no sé que deberia borrar o dejar, incluso el título del hilo ya casi nada tiene que ver con lo que se ha convertido esto. Si creen que deba borrar algo o modificar el título de alguna forma sientanse libres de proponer.

Saludos!!